# Encoded NSData for a url not saving to the documents directory

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, nsdocumentdirectory

I'm trying to save a html page locally on the iPhone's documents directory so I can load the page if the phone is in an offline state

My issue is when I call my NSData object directly to be written to file all the raw data is saved in a file in the documents directory.

But as soon as I cast my NSData to a NSString using encoding it stops writing the file in the documents directory. But when I print my **content** object it logs out the correct data. I just want that to be saved to a file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://anyurl"];
NSData *urlHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlHtmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
[myString writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

What could be causing the content to stop writing to my file?

Or if anyones got a better solution to view offline webpages rather than saving it to the documents directory?

Thanks

Comment: Have you dumped "content" to see if it contains all your data?

Comment: And this is useless: `[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", myString];`

Comment: (And `error:nil` can conceal a multitude of ills.)

Comment: Note that your problem has nothing to do with URLs and probably nothing to do with NSData.  Those should not be mentioned in your title.

Comment: Writing NSData directly should produce essentially the same result.

Comment: I'd recommend that you check `error` on your write.

Comment: No, when you print the object it's raw data. Just a bunch of numbers.

Comment: A regular character file is "just a bunch of numbers".  When you print an NSData it's "just a bunch of numbers", but if it's character data you can take an ASCII chart and decode the numbers into characters.  In general, NSStrings, when written to a file, are converted to single-byte form, basically reversing the "encoding" you used to convert an NSData to the NSString.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few things wrong with this. One: You don't use `stringWithFormat:` to append a path component. NSString has a method for that:

```
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
```

Two: NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy is part of an enum that is not defined for `writeToFile:`, so by using it, you're actually specifying `NSASCIIStringEncoding` without realizing it. In my opinion, just use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead.

Also, `NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", myString];` does absolutely nothing except duplicate myString. Erase that line and just use `[myString writeToFile:....`